# Best practice to print html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, templates

What is the best practice to print html in javascript without using "framework" like handlebarsjs, etc. ?

Something like:

```
var template = "<div>test test </div>";
$( '#div' ).html(template);
```

Thanks

Comment: Um...does jQuery qualify as a "framework"?

Comment: What do you expect as a template?

Comment: Just need a good practice to print html directly in javascript

Comment: as template just html like <div>test test </div> <i>test</i>

Comment: @user3037814 Well that's not a template since nothing varies based on some data, it's just a static HTML string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can have something a lot simpler than:

```
function myTemplate(data) {
    return [
        '<h3>', data.title, '</h3>'
        //...
    ].join('');
}

$('#div').html(myTemplate({ title: 'some title' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is relatively unclear, I will answer it to the best of my ability.

If you would like to set the content between a div flag with `id` attribute = `'div'` to the string `'hello'` then simply do something like this:

```
var content = 'hello';
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = content;
```

If you would like a further explanation, a more descriptive question would be appreciated.